# X Session Desktop integration

Tags: desktop, x11, session

When I run Emacs under an X11 session manager, it provides a `RestartCommand="emacs25 --smid=ef85455de14b4e6a8a8c39dae106b554 --chdir=/some/dir"`. I would like it to open the same files as last time, but only locally within the same smid! Is it possible to integrate the Desktop mode (or some other session mode) with this, so that each X11 session of Emacs (I'm planning to have multiple) restarts with its own set of files opened?